# Beautiful Soup 4 Python Webscraping price from website (not the same)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Someone automatically closed my post. This is not the same question as someone else. Do not close it please.

I am trying to get the price from the website. Can anyone please find the error in my code?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def priceTracker():
    url = ' https://www.britishairways.com/travel/book/public/en_gb/flightList?onds=LGW-AMS_2022-3-11&ad=1&yad=0&ch=0&inf=0&cabin=M&flex=LOWEST&usedChangeSearch=true'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
    #print(soup.prettify)
    price = soup.find(class_=" heading-sm ng-tns-c70-4 ng-star-inserted").next_sibling
    #print(soup) test if soup working properly
    print(price)
    
while True:
  priceTracker()
```

I have attached the DOM screen.
[image: Dom Screen]

I have attached the DOM screen of the price. I have updated the url (in case the url does not work, to get the url you go to the main website and press the search button)

Comment: Can you remove that `.nextSibling` and add `.text`

Comment: I may be wrong here, but is the `soup` variable (response.text) actually fetching anything? I ran it to see for I get blank responses on `price` and I see this in the `soup` when I print it:  `<p>Error 403 - You don't have enough permissions to proceed further</p>` besides the css part and the metadata.

Comment: the content is rendered through javascript. Doing a simple requests will only fetch the initial static html. You have 2 options: 1) fetch the data from the api - they do have an api, but requires the correct cookies, tokens, and headers. 2) Use Selenium to allow the page to render, then you can use beautifulsoup to parse

Comment: @chitown88 Can you please share the code of the second one?

Answer (score 1):

The page is rendered through javascript. You can get data through the api but requires a little work:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

s = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
s.get('https://www.britishairways.com', headers=headers)
cookies = s.cookies.get_dict()

cookieStr = ''
for k, v in cookies.items():
    cookieStr += f'{k}={v};'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
           'ba_integrity_tokenV1': '27f532c2f83fb5c560bcd25af3125d9658321fb753c1becc68735fd076ccbc46',
           'ba_api_context': 'https://www.britishairways.com/api/sc4',
           'ba_client_applicationName': 'ba.com',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer 09067a6cba44a44a7119a15c123064f6',
           'x-dtpc': '1$590599503_459h15vVJSUFBOHGPMRNQQHGCWULORUCSWNCPSO-0e0',
           'ba_client_sessionId': '72bb7a96-f635-4a55-bf5f-125f8c83c464',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Referer': 'https://www.britishairways.com/travel/book/public/en_gb/flightList?onds=LGW-AMS_2022-3-11&ad=1&yad=0&ch=0&inf=0&cabin=M&flex=LOWEST&usedChangeSearch=true',
           'Cookie': cookieStr}

url = 'https://www.britishairways.com/api/sc4/badotcomadapter-paa/rs/v1/flightavailability/search;ondwanted=1'
payload = {"ondSearches":[
    {"originLocationCode":"LGW",
     "destinationLocationCode":"AMS",
     "departureDate":"2022-03-11"
     }
    ],
    "cabin":"M",
    "ticketFlexibility":"LOWEST",
    "passengerMix":{
        "adultCount":1,
        "youngAdultCount":0,
        "childCount":0,
        "infantCount":0
        },
    "cug":'false',
    "includeCalendar":'true',
    "calendarDays":3,
    "baIntegrityTokenV1":"27f532c2f83fb5c560bcd25af3125d9658321fb753c1becc68735fd076ccbc46"}


jsonData = s.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()


calendarEntries = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['calendar']['calendarEntries'])
flightEvents = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['flightOption'],
                                 record_path=['flightEvents'])
availableCabinsForOption = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['flightOption'],
                                 record_path=['availableCabinsForOption'])
```

**Output:**

```
for table in [calendarEntries, flightEvents, availableCabinsForOption]:
    print(table)
         date  cheapestSegmentPrice  cheapestJourneyPrice
0  2022-03-08                 47.07                 47.07
1  2022-03-09                 54.07                 54.07
2  2022-03-10                 51.07                 51.07
3  2022-03-11                 80.07                 80.07
4  2022-03-12                 69.73                 69.73
5  2022-03-13                 51.07                 51.07
6  2022-03-14                 54.07                 54.07
        eventType duration  ... aircraft.aircraftCode aircraft.aircraftName
0  FLIGHT_SEGMENT  PT1H30M  ...                   319       Airbus A319 jet
1  FLIGHT_SEGMENT  PT1H25M  ...                   320       Airbus A320 jet
2  FLIGHT_SEGMENT  PT1H10M  ...                   E90        Embraer E190SR
3  FLIGHT_SEGMENT  PT1H25M  ...                   319       Airbus A319 jet
4  FLIGHT_SEGMENT   PT1H5M  ...                   E90        Embraer E190SR
5  FLIGHT_SEGMENT   PT1H5M  ...                   E90        Embraer E190SR
6  FLIGHT_SEGMENT  PT1H20M  ...                   319       Airbus A319 jet
7  FLIGHT_SEGMENT  PT1H25M  ...                   319       Airbus A319 jet

[8 rows x 32 columns]
    availabilityInSellingClass  ... fareBasisCode.BA2758
0                            9  ...                  NaN
1                            9  ...                  NaN
2                            9  ...                  NaN
3                            1  ...                  NaN
4                            1  ...                  NaN
5                            9  ...                  NaN
6                            9  ...                  NaN
7                            9  ...                  NaN
8                            9  ...                  NaN
9                            2  ...                  NaN
10                           2  ...                  NaN
11                           9  ...                  NaN
12                           9  ...                  NaN
13                           9  ...                  NaN
14                           9  ...                  NaN
15                           7  ...                  NaN
16                           7  ...                  NaN
17                           9  ...                  NaN
18                           2  ...                  NaN
19                           2  ...                  NaN
20                           9  ...                  NaN
21                           2  ...              [KZ0RO]
22                           2  ...              [KV2RO]
23                           9  ...             [DMV2RO]

[24 rows x 33 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def priceTracker():
    url = ' https://www.britishairways.com/travel/book/public/en_gb/flightList?onds=LGW-AMS_2022-3-11&ad=1&yad=0&ch=0&inf=0&cabin=M&flex=LOWEST&usedChangeSearch=true'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
    #print(soup.prettify)

    price = soup.find(class_="ng-star-inserted").text # changed
    #print(soup) test if soup working properly
    print(price)
    
while True:
  priceTracker()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I got this error when running the code. 

price = soup.find(class_=" heading-sm ng-tns-c70-4 ng-star-inserted").text  # changed
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Okay I have updated

Comment: I get the same error.  line 10, in priceTracker
    price = soup.find(class_="ng-star-inserted").text # changed
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'